# Scanning from File, last string is repeating

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm having some trouble with my code. I'm trying to read in some previous commands saved to a file, and place them in my array to use for later.

Here is my relevant piece of code:

```
    if( (pastHist = fopen("history.txt", "r+")) == NULL)
  {
pastHist = fopen("history.txt", "w+");
  }  
else
  {

printf("%s", "INSIDE the else!");
pastHist = fopen("history.txt", "r+");
fscanf(pastHist, "%s", fstring);
while (fstring != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s %s", "the read in string is: ", fstring);
    strcpy(cmndLine[cmndIndex], fstring);
    strcpy(cmndLinecpy[cmndIndex], fstring);
    cmndIndex++;
    cmndNum++;
    fscanf(pastHist, "%s", fstring);
  }
  }
```

Now the code writes to the file fine. (the writing part is held elsewhere). If I read from a file I wrote to before and the file said:

ls
rmdir angel
history

then i use this print statement to double check what i'm reading... it prints out 
"INSIDE the else! the read in string is: lsthe read in string is: rmdirthe read in string is: angelthe read in string is: historythe read in string is: historythe read in string is: history

... and it repeats that the last thing read in was history a million times. Why is this the case? I also tried with the while condition

```
while(getchar() != EOF)
```

but that gave me the same thing.

please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fstring` can never be set to NULL by that call to `fscanf`.  What you want to check is the *return value* of `fscanf`.

Your `getchar()` loop likewise does nothing useful - it's reading from the standard input, not from your file.

Comment: +1, and for the OP's reference `fscanf()` documentation [can be found here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Pay special attention to the return value, and make note to properly limit you `%s` to be your target buffer size less-one. buffer overflows suck.